# Django 2 - Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: django

I have a view called index:

```
def index(request):
"""Return index.html file"""
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

and a view called login:

```
def login(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(reverse('index'))

return render(request, 'login.html', {"login_form":login_form})
```

But I get an error after a login attempt:
`Reverse for 'index' not found. 'index' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`
The url pattern looks like:
`url(r'^login/$', login, name="login"),`

Surely `def index(request):` proves that the function exists?

Comment: Did you define a `namespace`in your url?

Comment: Where is the rest of your urls.py, specifically the index one which is the one it is complaining about?

Comment: @DanielRoseman you are correct... I don't have a url pattern for index in my urls.py